# CreateNamedQuery Null Pointer Exception

Tags: hibernate, exception, jpa, nullpointerexception

I have the following code :

```
TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createNamedQuery("QueryName", Employee.class);
```

which result the null pointer exception at hibernate.

Do anyone know why?

Below is the stack trace:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate,internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getReturnTypes();
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.getReturnTypes();

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String%29) on how to use the createNamedQuery method. You should replace "QueryName" with an actual query..

Comment: The queryName supplies here is just for illustration purposes. I had replace it with name of the query name of course. It seems like a bug in Hibernate.

Comment: it's "name - the name of a query defined in metadata" only if you use just one input parameter and you have two :)

Comment: TypedQuery return an object type and thus use for select JPQL only. Query return generic object tyoe and thus use for update or delete JPQL. By the way, thanks for point me to doc.